# Call JS function with Django fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I created a function for the email.

Here is the code

```
$('#id_email.form-control').keyup(function(){

    $('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-email">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
    }
});
```

But I have two fields for two different forms, so I don't want to write the same code for another field.

I know it's basic, but I don't know how to call this function for another field.

P.S. I work in django framework, if you have a solution in the view or template, I can give you more details

Comment: try `var allInputs = $( ":input" );`

Answer (score 0):

Drop the tag id `#id_email` and make it a class: `.email`, so that you can have more than one in the document.

```
$('.email.form-control').keyup(function(){
```

Within the handler, you have access to the DOM object where stuff happened via `this`. And you can access all its ancestors.

```
var form = $(this).parents('form');
```

That will walk through the ancestors of the element where the `keyup` happened, until it finds the `<form>` tag.

From there, you can access everything else, specific to the one form where the `keyup` happened.

```
$(form).find('span.error-keyup-email').remove();
```